# Data write in CSV of one column instead of row wise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

Developing application in Rails 2.

I am `generating CSV` file from database values. Get `emails of users` and generate CSV but write `emails in one column instead of Row.`

I tried lot but not found any solution for it.

## Below code of write csv in `controller file`

```
@users = User.all
tempArr = []

@users.each do |u|
  tempArr << u.email
end

respond_to do |format|
 format.csv {
  send_data tempArr.to_csv, :type => "text/csv", :filename => "usercsv.csv"
 }
end
```

## Data display like

```
a@gmail.com b@gmail.com c@gmail.com
```

## Want to display

```
a@gmail.com
b@gmail.com
c@gmail.com
```

Anyone have a idea or trick to sortout.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need data in row or in column, not clear for me?

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065130/rails-write-a-csv-file-column-wise

Comment: @OlegSobchuk Update Question please check it. Below display how I want to display.

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari can you help me from duplicate question?

Answer (score 1):

in `User` model

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    all.each do |user|
      csv << user.email
    end
  end
end
```

and than in controller you can use it

```
send_data @users.to_csv, :type => "text/csv", :filename => "usercsv.csv"
```

where `@users = User.all` or whatever

**EDITED**

your action should be

```
@users = User.all

respond_to do |format|
 format.csv {
  send_data @users.to_csv, :type => "text/csv", :filename => "usercsv.csv"
 }
end
```

**EDITED 2**

add to `config/application.rb` or just to model

```
require 'csv'
```

Comment: @ users.to_csv then write whole objects of @user. Still in one row all data. Nothing change.

Comment: did you add `.to_csv` method to `User` model?

Comment: remove `@users.each do |u|
  tempArr << u.email
end`

Comment: .to_csv is default function of may be take all data without call modal method